# Installshield 2011: Take path from one window, take text from second

Tags: file, input, dialog, installshield, installscript

Good day, everyone. I have that task assigned which consists in creating simple installscript-only project, that should have 2 windows: first will prompt user to enter a path and create text file in this specified location, while second will promt for text input and save anything user writes into this text file.

Funny point is that I have small installshield experience (completed tutorials... well, yeah, that's all) and very little programming experience on top of that. As far as i understand, I should first create two custom dialog windows (for example by cloning them from standard ones), then create .rul files with functions, determining behavior for each. After which, include them into main setup.rul and call functions at specific point of time.

Question is - what exact dialog windows/functions/points of time will be best for such task? For reference i searched into "Serial Number Validation Sample Project" but, honestly, the way it customized default window is just confused me even more... So, please, can anybody help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here's working solution.

Asked that same question at flexera forums, and here's what I got:

> Off the top of my head (without InstallShield handy to check this) 1)
>   Create an InstallScript project, just accept all of the defaults in
>   the new project wizard unless you want to add localization or
>   something. 2) Your description implies that you do not need
>   maintenance (repair, modify, uninstall) support. If correct go to
>   Project\Settings and on the Maintenance tab select 'no uninstall or
>   maintenance'. 3) You can put your code at the top of the
>   OnFirstUIBefore function and then call Exit so that the rest of that
>   default code is never executed, since you are not installing anything.
>
> As part of your InstallShield IDE, in the Start menu (for IS2012
>   Spring) is a tool that demonstrates all of the built in dialogs. You
>   can look through those choices and select the dialog that is best for
>   your situation. It sounds like you want to:
>
> Call AskPath or SdAskDestPath (there are several other possibilities)
>
> Then call AskText and save that string.
>
> If you need to make layout or text changes to the default dialogs look
>   at your Dialogs view and select which ever dialog you selected above
>   and edit it. (If you decide to use skins make sure you select the skin
>   before you make any dialog layout changes.)
>
> Then do something similar to the functional body of the WriteLine
>   example http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield14langref/LangrefWriteLine_Example.htm
>
> The actual WriteLine example function prototype is for a MSI custom
>   action which is not what you want. Ignore the function protoype and
>   just use the code in your project to create the file at the path you
>   already collected and write the line of text that you collected.
>
> Then call Exit;

(big thanks to user phill_mn for that answer)

And here's the code for setup.rul:

```
#include "ifx.h"

function OnFirstUIBefore()
    number nvFileHandle;
    string  svResult;
    string  szTargetPath, szFeatures;
    BOOL bLicenseAccepted;

begin   

AskPath ("Please choose a path where text file will be saved","c:\\",szTargetPath);

MessageBox("File yourtext.txt wiil be created or overwritten at " +szTargetPath, INFORMATION);

AskText ("Please enter some text to save into that file", "Text goes here", svResult); 

OpenFileMode (FILE_MODE_APPEND);

   if (CreateFile (nvFileHandle, szTargetPath, "yourtext.txt") < 0) then 
        MessageBox ("Creating failed.", SEVERE); 
        abort; 
   else 

        if (WriteLine(nvFileHandle, svResult) < 0) then 
            MessageBox ("Writing failed.", SEVERE); 
        else 
            MessageBox ("Success.", INFORMATION); 
        endif; 

    endif; 

    CloseFile (nvFileHandle); 

Do(EXIT); 

    return 0;
end;
```